# Python - Pandas - Create columns from row entries

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to create a useable Pandas dataframe from a particular .csv file. The file has one column to identify the type of test that the datain the row is for, two columns that identify the device that is being measured, and the rest of the columns contain the data.

The input .csv file follows this format:

```
testtype1, device1name, device1info, meas_1, meas_2, meas_3, ... ... , meas_n
testtype2, device1name, device1info, meas_1, meas_2, meas_3, ... ... , meas_n
testtype3, device1name, device1info, meas_1, meas_2, meas_3, ... ... , meas_n
testtype1, device2name, device2info, meas_1, meas_2, meas_3, ... ... , meas_n
testtype2, device2name, device2info, meas_1, meas_2, meas_3, ... ... , meas_n
testtype2, device2name, device2info, meas_1, meas_2, meas_3, ... ... , meas_n
...        ...          ...          ...     ...     ...               ...
```

And so on. I am trying to get this data into this format:

```
devicename    deviceinfo    testtype1   testtype2   testtype3
device1name   device1info   meas_1      meas_1      meas_1
device1name   device1info   meas_2      meas_2      meas_2
device1name   device1info   meas_3      meas_3      meas_3
...           ...           ...         ...         ...
device1name   device1info   meas_n      meas_n      meas_n
device2name   device2info   meas_1      meas_1      meas_1
device2name   device2info   meas_2      meas_2      meas_2
...           ...           ...         ...         ...
```

I read the file using `pd.read_csv(filename)`, but once I have the data I get stuck. I have looked at using `df.pivot`, and also transposing the dataframe slice with the measurements, however I have no idea where to go from here. I am very new to Python so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table would be the correct way to do this - start off slowly - and then add complexity.

From the look of your data

```
 new_df = pd.pivot_table(orig_dataframe,index=['device1name','device1info'],values=['Col1','Col2'])
```

If you then wanted to do some **numpy** maths calls you would add a

```
,aggfunc=[np.sum,len]
```

To the pivot_table call

Comment: I am trying to use the `pd.pivot_table()` function, but it is taking the mean of each `meas_n` of the different tests. What I want to do is create a new row for each `meas_n`, with columns for `'devicename'` and `'deviceinfo'` filled in accordingly, similar to an SQL database format. It doesn't seem that there is anything built in for this?

Comment: I ended up solving this by looping through each line, using string.split() for the data and writing this to a StringIO object in the format I wanted. I then passed this to read_csv() and obtained the data in the format I wanted.